# Unable to install "App" Xcode 11.5+ iOS 13.5.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

when you connect a second iPhone, it gives this error, details below. I tried to be guided by discussions:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124031 ,

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242678/xcode-error-the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-re

Did not help

```
Details

Unable to install "App"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
--
The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008021)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012646e81a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001264aff70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d16b155 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001264afca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000126326e91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d29e7f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d2a0436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68c7f6c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68c80658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68c85c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68c865d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff68c8fc09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff68edaa3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff68ed9b77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G46c)
Xcode 11.5 (16139)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the free version of Apple Developer. They restrict how many devices you can push your app to, to 3 devices.

To free up space just delete the apps you already have installed by going Window -> Device and Simulators.

Then press SHIFT+CMD+K to clean the project; this worked for me!